# How to save binary content of an attribute in a pdf file in apache nifi?

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I make a SOAP request to an endpoint and thus capture a property that is  and in this property is the binary of the file, I want to convert the value of this property to base64 and save this binfile in a pdf file

Response:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <downloadEletronicFileResponse xmlns="urn:document">
             <return>
                <item>
                       <NMFILE>nameoffile.pdf</NMFILE>
                       <BINFILE>JVBERi0xLjQNCiXIycrLDQoxM.... #binfile HERE!
                </item>
             </return>
          </downloadEletronicFileResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I can capture the attribute after the request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzxGJ.png)

I'm having trouble because I can't save this captured attribute as a pdf file in the putfile processor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An6iD.png)

I've already tried using processors and updateattribute, replacetext but I can't convert it to PDF and save only the binary string that is in an attribute in the flowfile

Answer (score 0):

How is your data getting into NiFi? You don't want to store that (base64-encoded or not) in an attribute as they are always interpreted as strings using the system default character set (often UTF-8), and attributes have an effective/recommended size limit of 1 MB. You should instead store it as the content of the FlowFile which will respect its format. If it is base64-encoded you can then use the [EncodeContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.23.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EncodeContent/index.html) processor to decode (it does both encoding and decoding despite its name), or if your version of NiFi doesn't have that processor, you can use the `Base64Encode` processor (now deprecated in favor of `EncodeContent`).

If your content is already in binary PDF format and you put it as bytes into the FlowFile content, it will be honored as such and you can use `PutFile` without any extra processing (decoding, e.g.)